# Xcode rearranges button layout when built?

Tags: xcode, button

I've created this calculator interface in xcode:

[image]

Unfortunately, whenever I build the app in Xcode, the buttons automatically rearrange.

[image]

I can't figure out how to solve the problem - I assume it's something to do with AutoLayout in Xcode, but I can't find any solutions to the issue online.

I'm sure it's something very simple, I just can't see the solution!